# Not able to get response from smack

Tags: android, connection, kotlin, ejabberd, smack

I am using the smack to connect ejabbard server.

TO connect with ejabbard server through smack using following code

```
val config=XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setXmppDomain(mDomainName)
                    .setUsernameAndPassword(mUsername,mPassword)
                    .setDebuggerEnabled(true)

            mConnection= XMPPTCPConnection(config.build())

            Log.v("Current status ",mConnection!!.isConnected().toString())
            mConnection!!.connect()
```

But end up getting the error/warning:

```
4-15 12:09:22.626 2685-3195/com.example.itstym.kotlinchat I/DNSUtil: Could not resolve DNS SRV resource records for _xmpp-client._tcp.replica3377.cloudapp.net. Consider adding those.
04-15 12:09:23.033 2685-3208/com.example.itstym.kotlinchat D/SMACK: SENT (1): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='replica3377.cloudapp.net' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='user2@replica3377.cloudapp.net' xml:lang='en'>
04-15 12:09:23.189 2685-3209/com.example.itstym.kotlinchat D/SMACK: RECV (1): <?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream id='3002662766383892485' version='1.0' xml:lang='en' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' to='user2@replica3377.cloudapp.net' from='replica3377.cloudapp.net' xmlns='jabber:client'>
04-15 12:09:23.190 2685-3209/com.example.itstym.kotlinchat D/SMACK: RECV (1): <stream:features><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
04-15 12:09:28.846 2685-2754/com.example.itstym.kotlinchat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <stream:error><connection-timeout xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/></stream:error></stream:stream>
```

after 30 sec or so I am getting another error

```
04-15 12:09:28.853 2685-2754/com.example.itstym.kotlinchat W/AbstractXMPPConnection: Connection XMPPTCPConnection[not-authenticated] (0) closed with error
                                                                                     org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$StreamErrorException: connection-timeout You can read more about the meaning of this stream error at http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-error-conditions
                                                                                     <stream:error><connection-timeout xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/></stream:error>
                                                                                         at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1046)
                                                                                         at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:980)
                                                                                         at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:996)
                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

But when I check in ejabbard server session is started for the user. Also using converse.js I can verify the user is logged in.

SO I think I am not getting the response from smack.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at SMACK's documentation about creating a connection, you're missing a call to `connection.login()` so it times out after 5 seconds. (See delta between the last 2 RECV messages)

Documentation: https://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/documentation/connections.html

Comment: If I am making only connect request then also it should send me the connect successfully msg. By the way I also tried to call login() method also. But got same response.

Comment: @Kiskae can you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491831/how-do-i-get-the-message-from-the-message-id-in-smack