# How do I get the message from the message id in smack.

Tags: android, message, kotlin, smack, packet

I am trying to fetch the chat history using below function:

```
    var mamManager:MamManager= MamManager.getInstanceFor(connection)
    var prevMsg=mamManager.queryArchive(JidCreate.entityBareFrom(jid)).forwardedMessages

        println(msg.forwardedStanza)
```

But I am getting the output as

```
04-19 14:17:58.414 7964-7964/com.example.itstym.smackchat I/System.out: Message Stanza [to=user2@replica3377.cloudapp.net,from=user1@replica3377.cloudapp.net/307135084148417199024926,id=qQ73x-27,]
```

I can also get stanza id using msg.forwardedStanza.stanzaId but how will i get the msg text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the forwarded Stanza to Message and call getBody().

Comment: hey can you look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541753/not-able-to-receive-group-message-using-smack?noredirect=1#comment74135452_43541753

Answer (score 1):

The getBody() is for Message and the ForwardedStanza extends Stanza so it can be Message, IQ or Presence.

Try this:

```
    if (forwarded.getForwardedStanza() instanceof Message) {
        String body = ((Message) forwarded.getForwardedStanza()).getBody();
    }
```